# Create and Publish a node_modules package without it's own node_modules

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, npm-publish

I had created a project using  `ReactJs` and `Material UI`

And then I was building and publishing the whole project

When I want to install this module in client-side with

```
npm install clientsso/BuildTest
```

it workes fine, but  it comes with its own `node_modules` folder

so I force build to create a single file in another folder and i publish this folder

```
build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file BuildTest/index.js
```

but when I re-install, it always asks for "Material UI", modules used by this custom package

is there any solution to force the client to install all necessary modules for this package 
in his folder "./node_modules/BuildTest"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you remove the `node_modules` folder before publishing?

Comment: There is a guide on creating a NodeJS module: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules

Comment: @VictorF no I didn't

Comment: I don't know if you should do that - maybe. If you look at any package in the node_modules folder it doesn't have a node_modules folder

Comment: @VictorF Some have node_modules like "cacache" but I don't know if it comes with the module or npm will fetch its own package.json and add   node module to it

Comment: so far I have not understood the role of peerDependencies